# How to use picture in picture mode for a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

We all know that by picture in picture mode we can pop out the video and that video will be on the top always, can we do this for a button also?
I am making a web project in which I want to pop out a button for the user and this button should be on top always, it should not go back to any other window, when we work on any other window.
So, do anyone have any idea how can i do it by html, css and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. PIP is only supported on video elements, and even then, browser support is close to none https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API. Android devices have an API called "bubbles" that does basically what you want, but it's for native apps, not web pages https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles.